# Where is background process execute?

Tags: go

Ok, for example we have some blocking operation. Few questions.

1. How Go understand that it's blocking operation and it's time to do `yield` (I do not know how it's name in Go)
2. For example blocking operation is Reading file or some heavy calculations. Where are they processing? If I right understand goroutines should delegate it's processing for example to system threads. Am I right? But does it's mean that for every blocking operation new system thread is starting? If yes it's seems that we would have same problem with context-switching when would have a lot of system threads.

Comment: It is operating system specific. Linux has multiplexing calls (like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)) and non-blocking IO (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [fcntl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) with `F_SETOWN` etc...) and asynchronous IO (see [aio(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html)...). Your usage of [*process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) word is wrong. Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ & http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/

Comment: Your question is wrongly formulated, and is too broad to get an answer in a few paragraphs. Once you have understood more about operating systems, you could dive into the source code of Go runtime, since it is free software. On Linux, you might also experiment with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). BTW, Go runtime is using [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) with [split stacks](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks)

Comment: The Go runtime scheduler implements M×N multiplexing of the *goroutines* (Go's concurrency primitives) over some dynamically changing number of OS threads. While Go scheduler gets updated almost any Go release, the basics of its implementation explained [here](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) still hold true, so please read it.

Comment: I should also say that the question as stated is unfit for SO; please direct such questions to the `golang-nuts` mailing list or the `/r/golang` Subreddit for instance.

Comment: Also note that goroutines are not quite like coroutines in other languages. You do not *need* to call any yield function ever (although `runtime.Gosched` exists for performance tuning).